# Use QMap or Qlist container if I want to search a name in a list of names

Tags: c++, qt

I want to maintain a list of `Names` and then search if the literal `"a name"` exists in the list.

Should I use a QMap:

```
QMap<QString, bool> Names;
Names.find("a name");
```

Or a QList:

```
QList<QString> Names:
bool found = false;
foreach(QString name, Names){
    if (name == "a name"){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you may want to use is QSet
You can search whether `a name` is in the `Names` by calling [contains()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qset.html#contains) method

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the container to have any order, use a `QSet<QString>`.